# Multiple nested expressions in ANTLR

Tags: c#, expression, antlr, grammar

Parser does not see equality expression:
`extraneous input '=' expecting {<EOF>, '~', '(', OPERATOR, IDENTIFIER, NUMBER, STRING}`

Even error is not clear, it tells it expects operator, but `=` is a defined operator.

Also I achieve 2 member access expressions instead of 3.

This is the grammar:

```js
grammar xxx;
 
parse: expression+ EOF; 
 
expression:
    expression op=OPERATOR expression                       #binaryExpression
    | op=OPERATOR expression                                #unaryPrefixExpression
    | expression op=OPERATOR                                #unarPostfixExpression
    | member_expression                                     #memberExpression
    | OPENING_PARENTHESIS expression CLOSING_PARENTHESIS    #parenthesisExpression 
    | STRING                                                #stringExpression
    | NUMBER                                                #numberExpression
    | NEGATE expression                                     #negationExpression
    ;

member_expression: 
    IDENTIFIER (DOT(IDENTIFIER DOT?))*
    ;

// operators
PLUS: '+' ;
MINUS: '-' ;
BIGGER_THAN: '>' ;
LESS_THAN: '<' ;
BIGGER_THAN_OR_EQUALS: '>=' ;
LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS: '<=' ;
NEGATE: '~' ;
EQUALITY: '=' ;

OPENING_PARENTHESIS: '(' ;
CLOSING_PARENTHESIS: ')' ;

fragment LOGICAL_OPERATOR:
    | EQUALITY
    | BIGGER_THAN_OR_EQUALS 
    | LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS
    | LESS_THAN
    | BIGGER_THAN
    ;

OPERATOR: 
    PLUS 
    | MINUS 
    | NEGATE 
    | LOGICAL_OPERATOR
    ;

DOT: '.' ;
IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;
    
// literals
NUMBER: [0-9] + ('.' [0-9] +)? ;
STRING : '"' .*? '"' ;

WS: [ \t\n]+ -> skip ;
ANY: . ;
```

---

This is the expression:

`context.Previous.Output.previous_value2 = 123`

Tree string:

`([] ([6] ([16 6] context . Previous .)) ([6] ([16 6] Output . previous_value2)) = ([6] 123) <EOF>)`
`

As you can see there are 2x member access expressions, then unrecognized equality operator, then number expression.

I want to get:

3 separate member access expressions

1 equality expression

Comment: What does `IDENTIFIER (DOT(IDENTIFIER DOT?))*` mean to you? Pretty sure it doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: Focus on lexer rules first. Print out the tokens recognized, not the tree. But, for printing the tree later on, use "tree.ToStringTree()" not "tree.ToString()". OPERATOR almost never ever recognized, and you ignored the warning message from the Antlr tool `xxx.g4:41:0: non-fragment lexer rule OPERATOR can match the empty string`. Lexer rules ***must not ever*** match the empty string. Unfold the right-hand side of OPERATOR into the right-hand side of `expression`, and get rid of OPERATOR rule entirely--completely wrong Get rid of NEGATE--never matches.

Comment: @kaby76 I think your browser font is making `MINUS` and `NEGATE` look alike. They're not the same: one is a minus and the other a tilde. I.e. `NEGATE` can be matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lexer rules always match in 1 way: the lexer tries to match as much characters  as possible and when 2 (or more) rules match the same characters, the rule defined first will win. So take the rule `PLUS` and `OPERATOR`:

```
PLUS: '+' ;

...

OPERATOR: 
    PLUS 
    | MINUS 
    | NEGATE 
    | LOGICAL_OPERATOR
    ;
```

for the input string `"+"`, the lexer will always produce a `PLUS` token, never a `OPERATOR` token.

The solution: change the `OPERATOR` and `LOGICAL_OPERATOR` lexer rules into parser rules:

```
grammar xxx;

parse: expression+ EOF;

expression:
    expression op=operator expression                       #binaryExpression
    | op=unary_operator expression                          #unaryPrefixExpression
    | expression op=operator                                #unarPostfixExpression
    | member_expression                                     #memberExpression
    | OPENING_PARENTHESIS expression CLOSING_PARENTHESIS    #parenthesisExpression
    | STRING                                                #stringExpression
    | NUMBER                                                #numberExpression
    | NEGATE expression                                     #negationExpression
    ;

member_expression:
    IDENTIFIER (DOT(IDENTIFIER DOT?))*
    ;

operator:
    EQUALITY
    | BIGGER_THAN_OR_EQUALS
    | LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS
    | LESS_THAN
    | BIGGER_THAN
    | unary_operator
    ;

unary_operator:
    PLUS
    | MINUS
    | NEGATE
    ;

// operators
PLUS: '+' ;
MINUS: '-' ;
BIGGER_THAN: '>' ;
LESS_THAN: '<' ;
BIGGER_THAN_OR_EQUALS: '>=' ;
LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS: '<=' ;
NEGATE: '~' ;
EQUALITY: '=' ;

OPENING_PARENTHESIS: '(' ;
CLOSING_PARENTHESIS: ')' ;

DOT: '.' ;
IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;

// literals
NUMBER: [0-9] + ('.' [0-9] +)? ;
STRING : '"' .*? '"' ;

WS: [ \t\n]+ -> skip ;
ANY: . ;
```

Also, the following would match an empty string:

```
fragment LOGICAL_OPERATOR:
    | EQUALITY
    | BIGGER_THAN_OR_EQUALS 
    | LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS
    | LESS_THAN
    | BIGGER_THAN
    ;
```

you probably meant:

```
fragment LOGICAL_OPERATOR:
    EQUALITY
    | BIGGER_THAN_OR_EQUALS 
    | LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS
    | LESS_THAN
    | BIGGER_THAN
    ;
```

Btw, a better way to print the tree is to use `toStringTree(Parser)`:

```java
String source = "context.Previous.Output.previous_value2 = 123";
xxxLexer lexer = new xxxLexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
xxxParser parser = new xxxParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
ParseTree tree = parser.parse();
System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));
```

which will print:

```
(parse (expression (member_expression context . Previous .)) (expression (expression (member_expression Output . previous_value2)) (operator =) (expression 123)) <EOF>)
```